# form styling vertical align

Tags: css, webforms, styling

I am having trouble styling a form.  The section labelled destination group I cannot get it to align vertically.  See screenshot below.  I have added color borders to help with debugging of the css.

[image]

I have created a js fiddle for this
http://jsfiddle.net/uuNTC/

Below is a stripped down version of the code

HTML

```
<ul id="ulFilterList">
  <li>
     <div class="filterLabel" id="labelDates">Dates</div>

          <input type="text" value="03/09/2012" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" class="dateInputs">
          <input type="text" value="09/09/2012" name="dateTo" id="dateTo" class="dateInputs">

  </li>
  <li>   
      <div class="filterLabel" id="labelOnRequest">Include "On Request" With:</div>
      <select name="onRequest" id="onRequest">
          <option selected="selected" value="1">Stop Sell</option>
          <option value="2">Available</option>
      </select>

  </li>
  <li>

      <div class="filterLabel" id="labelDestinationGroups">Destination Group:</div>
          <select size="10" multiple="multiple" name="destinationGroups[]" id="destinationGroups">

            <option value="Tunisia All">Tunisia All</option>
            <option value="Turkey All">Turkey All</option>
            <option value="Turkey PNR">Turkey PNR</option>
            <option value="UAE Abu Dhabi ">UAE Abu Dhabi </option>
            <option value="UAE All Dubai">UAE All Dubai</option>
            <option value="VIE">VIE</option>
            <option value="VIE">MORE</option>
            <option value="VIE">MORE</option>
            <option value="VIE">MORE</option>
            <option value="VIE">MORE</option>
            <option value="VIE">MORE</option>
            <option value="VIE">MORE</option>
          </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the css

```
ul#ulFilterList,
ul#ulFilterList li  { margin: 0px; padding: 0px }

.dateInputs { margin:0px; text-align:left; width: 50px; display: inline-block;   }

#ulFilterList { width: 100% }

ul#ulFilterList li
{
  list-style:none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}


.filterLabel {
    font-weight: normal;  
    width: 29%;  
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 11px ;
    margin-top: auto
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the benefits of using `display: inline-block;` is that you can specify a vertical-alignment. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuNTC/8/) I've set the vertical-alignment for the `.filterLabel` elements to `vertical-align: top;`. On the down-side, you'll need to return to the default `vertical-align: baseline;` for labels that are next to single-line inputs (the "Dates" and "Include 'On Request' With" labels), or style the corresponding `INPUT` elements upwards a bit.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Can it be vertically aligned in the middle?

Comment: Yep :-p `vertical-align: middle;` instead of `vertical-align: top;`, but you need to specify `vertical-align: middle;` on the neighboring `SELECT` as well. The `SELECT` and the `LABEL` will then be aligned to the middle of each other.

Comment: Trying to get the elements aligned a little better when all have `vertical-align: top;`: http://jsfiddle.net/uuNTC/18/ Don't know how it looks in anything but Chrome, but the single-option `SELECT` alignment is still off and I can't seem to fix it… Giving up for now.